# New Battery Acting Weird

Tags: battery-life

I have a Dell Vostro 14 3468 and recently my battery died.

So I bought a new replacement battery on 6th of October, 2020. I followed all the instructions mention and did my first charge to 100%.

When I opened the battery report, I came to know that the full charge capacity is around 32500 mWh while designed capacity is 41440 mWh which equals 21 percent wear.

I re-calibrated the battery and the wear went down to 9 percent with full charge capacity around 37500 mWh.

While using the laptop, when my battery reached 25%, it suddenly went down to 6% although I had used the laptop on battery for almost 4 hours during this time.
I tried re-calibrating again and the wear went up to 27%. One more try and it is at 28%.

Although it seems that the laptop is providing 4 hours of normal usage on battery but sometimes it acts weird. For example, I charged my battery to full 100% and started using it.
When it reached 95%, I plugged it in and it immediately showed Full charged(100%). When disconnected the charger, it went back to 95%.

Please guide me whether it is a calibration issue or an issue with the battery.

Here is the present battery report.

```
Battery report 

COMPUTER NAME 
DESKTOP-PT8THP0
SYSTEM PRODUCT NAME 
Dell Inc. Vostro 14-3468
BIOS 
3.4.0 05/10/2019
OS BUILD 
18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
PLATFORM ROLE 
Mobile
CONNECTED STANDBY 
Not supported
REPORT TIME 
2020-10-09 00:54:21
Installed batteries 
Information about each currently installed battery 



BATTERY 1
NAME
DELL VN3N047
MANUFACTURER
SMP
SERIAL NUMBER
9001
CHEMISTRY
LION
DESIGN CAPACITY
41,440 mWh 

FULL CHARGE CAPACITY
29,467 mWh 
CYCLE COUNT
- 
Recent usage
Power states over the last 3 days 





START TIME 
STATE 
SOURCE 
CAPACITY REMAINING 
2020-10-06 15:52:04
Active 
Battery 
66 % 
21,371 mWh 
16:30:55
Suspended 

46 % 
14,844 mWh 
17:11:46
Active 
Battery 
45 % 
14,578 mWh 
17:24:30
Suspended 

5 % 
1,732 mWh 
17:26:49
Active 
Battery 
4 % 
1,288 mWh 
17:30:14
Active 
AC 
2 % 
681 mWh 
17:31:44
Suspended 

3 % 
1,125 mWh 
19:33:54
Active 
AC 
100 % 
32,560 mWh 
19:33:56
Suspended 

100 % 
32,560 mWh 
19:34:31
Active 
Battery 
99 % 
32,382 mWh 
20:32:26
Active 
AC 
78 % 
25,486 mWh 
20:32:30
Battery changed 
AC 
-
-
20:32:30
Active 
AC 
-
-
20:33:29
Battery changed 
AC 
-
-
20:33:29
Active 
AC 
-
-
20:33:31
Suspended 

-
-
20:41:04
Battery changed 
AC 
84 % 
32,205 mWh 
20:41:04
Active 
AC 
84 % 
32,205 mWh 
20:47:04
Active 
Battery 
88 % 
33,996 mWh 
21:06:51
Suspended 

81 % 
31,213 mWh 
21:08:50
Battery changed 
Battery 
78 % 
25,397 mWh 
21:08:50
Active 
Battery 
78 % 
25,397 mWh 
21:08:50
Suspended 

78 % 
25,397 mWh 
21:09:25
Active 
Battery 
78 % 
25,323 mWh 
21:13:22
Suspended 

76 % 
24,657 mWh 
21:18:17
Active 
Battery 
72 % 
23,547 mWh 
23:43:44
Suspended 

17 % 
5,683 mWh 
2020-10-07 01:53:19
Active 
AC 
100 % 
37,651 mWh 
01:57:59
Active 
Battery 
100 % 
37,651 mWh 
02:00:55
Suspended 

99 % 
37,178 mWh 
08:27:04
Active 
Battery 
98 % 
36,956 mWh 
12:25:14
Active 
AC 
6 % 
2,176 mWh 
12:39:52
Active 
Battery 
18 % 
6,808 mWh 
12:40:06
Active 
AC 
18 % 
6,793 mWh 
12:43:08
Active 
Battery 
21 % 
7,726 mWh 
12:43:15
Active 
AC 
21 % 
7,726 mWh 
13:15:48
Active 
Battery 
48 % 
17,982 mWh 
14:30:20
Suspended 

26 % 
9,975 mWh 
17:26:26
Active 
AC 
100 % 
33,862 mWh 
17:31:24
Active 
Battery 
100 % 
33,862 mWh 
19:18:51
Suspended 

5 % 
1,806 mWh 
19:20:01
Active 
Battery 
5 % 
1,598 mWh 
19:20:01
Suspended 

5 % 
1,598 mWh 
19:20:36
Active 
Battery 
5 % 
1,495 mWh 
19:26:20
Suspended 

2 % 
725 mWh 
21:12:48
Active 
AC 
83 % 
24,923 mWh 
21:18:30
Active 
Battery 
88 % 
26,477 mWh 
21:18:38
Active 
AC 
88 % 
26,462 mWh 
21:48:20
Suspended 

100 % 
30,074 mWh 
21:51:06
Active 
AC 
100 % 
30,074 mWh 
21:55:16
Active 
Battery 
100 % 
30,074 mWh 
2020-10-08 01:59:32
Suspended 

5 % 
1,613 mWh 
10:25:31
Active 
Battery 
100 % 
29,467 mWh 
10:25:31
Suspended 

100 % 
29,467 mWh 
10:26:06
Active 
Battery 
100 % 
29,467 mWh 
10:26:06
Active 
AC 
100 % 
29,467 mWh 
10:27:01
Active 
Battery 
100 % 
29,467 mWh 
13:09:45
Active 
AC 
39 % 
11,470 mWh 
14:16:11
Suspended 

98 % 
28,964 mWh 
2020-10-09 00:04:39
Active 
Battery 
97 % 
28,697 mWh 
00:54:21
Report generated 
Battery 
73 % 
21,638 mWh 
Battery usage
Battery drains over the last 3 days 






START TIME 
STATE 
DURATION 
ENERGY DRAINED 
2020-10-06 15:52:04
Active 
0:38:51
20 % 
6,527 mWh 

17:11:46
Active 
0:12:43
39 % 
12,846 mWh 

17:26:49
Active 
0:03:24
2 % 
607 mWh 

19:34:31
Active 
0:57:54
21 % 
6,896 mWh 

20:47:04
Active 
0:19:47
7 % 
2,783 mWh 

21:08:50
Active 
0:00:00
-
-

21:09:25
Active 
0:03:57
2 % 
666 mWh 

21:18:17
Active 
2:25:27
55 % 
17,864 mWh 

01:57:59
Active 
0:02:55
1 % 
473 mWh 

08:27:04
Active 
3:58:10
92 % 
34,780 mWh 

12:39:52
Active 
0:00:13
-
15 mWh 

12:43:08
Active 
0:00:07
-
-

13:15:48
Active 
1:14:31
21 % 
8,007 mWh 

17:31:24
Active 
1:47:26
95 % 
32,056 mWh 

19:20:01
Active 
0:00:00
-
-

19:20:36
Active 
0:05:44
3 % 
770 mWh 

21:18:30
Active 
0:00:08
-
15 mWh 

21:55:16
Active 
4:04:16
95 % 
28,461 mWh 

10:25:31
Active 
0:00:00
-
-

10:26:06
Active 
0:00:00
-
-

10:27:01
Active 
2:42:43
61 % 
17,997 mWh 

2020-10-09 00:04:39
Active 
0:49:41
24 % 
7,059 mWh 
Usage history 
History of system usage on AC and battery 








BATTERY DURATION 

AC DURATION 
PERIOD 
ACTIVE 
CONNECTED STANDBY 

ACTIVE 
CONNECTED STANDBY 
2020-08-09 - 2020-08-16
0:00:13
-

11:28:19
-
2020-08-16 - 2020-08-23
0:00:22
-

5:23:30
-
2020-08-23 - 2020-08-30
2:28:27
-

15:48:40
-
2020-08-30 - 2020-09-06
0:21:39
-

26:52:35
-
2020-09-06 - 2020-09-13
0:10:31
-

11:55:39
-
2020-09-13 - 2020-09-20
0:08:44
-

5:51:25
-
2020-09-20 - 2020-09-27
0:04:09
-

28:29:20
-
2020-09-27
-
-

5:18:57
-
2020-09-28
0:00:01
-

7:53:07
-
2020-09-29
0:02:22
-

1:01:50
-
2020-09-30
0:06:28
-

10:34:43
-
2020-10-01
0:02:05
-

6:43:50
-
2020-10-02
0:08:46
-

4:55:41
-
2020-10-03
-
-

3:16:04
-
2020-10-04
-
-

2:59:17
-
2020-10-05
0:00:04
-

-
-
2020-10-06
4:41:55
-

0:08:34
-
2020-10-07
9:13:04
-

1:36:32
-
2020-10-08
4:42:11
-

1:07:20
-
Battery capacity history 
Charge capacity history of the system's batteries 



PERIOD
FULL CHARGE CAPACITY 
DESIGN CAPACITY 
2020-08-09 - 2020-08-16
2,812 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-08-16 - 2020-08-23
10,953 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-08-23 - 2020-08-30
32,087 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-08-30 - 2020-09-06
4,726 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-09-06 - 2020-09-13
4,677 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-09-13 - 2020-09-20
3,405 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-09-20 - 2020-09-27
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-09-27
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-09-28
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-09-29
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-09-30
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-10-01
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-10-02
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-10-03
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-10-04
2,054 mWh 
41,383 mWh 
2020-10-05
2,057 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-10-06
32,878 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-10-07
35,478 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
2020-10-08
29,730 mWh 
41,440 mWh 
Battery life estimates 
Battery life estimates based on observed drains 








AT FULL CHARGE 

AT DESIGN CAPACITY 
PERIOD 
ACTIVE
CONNECTED STANDBY

ACTIVE
CONNECTED STANDBY
2020-08-09 - 2020-08-16
0:13:32
-

3:19:31
-
2020-08-16 - 2020-08-23
0:45:38
-

2:52:40
-
2020-08-23 - 2020-08-30
3:26:56
-

4:27:16
-
2020-08-30 - 2020-09-06
0:30:26
-

4:26:56
-
2020-09-06 - 2020-09-13
0:09:46
-

1:26:34
-
2020-09-13 - 2020-09-20
0:23:21
-

4:44:17
-
2020-09-20 - 2020-09-27
0:16:02
-

5:23:15
-
2020-09-27
-
-

-
-
2020-09-28
-
-

-
-
2020-09-29
0:08:53
-

2:58:58
-
2020-09-30
0:14:29
-

4:51:54
-
2020-10-01
0:26:27
-

8:52:55
-
2020-10-02
0:16:54
-

5:40:47
-
2020-10-03
-
-

-
-
2020-10-04
-
-

-
-
2020-10-05
-
-

-
-
2020-10-06
3:12:20
-

4:02:26
-
2020-10-07
3:27:47
-

4:02:42
-
2020-10-08
4:58:26
-

6:55:58
-
Current estimate of battery life based on all observed drains since OS install 







Since OS install 
3:09:40
-

4:26:44
-
```